# How can I run smart contract on geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, console

I know that when smart contracts run in Ethereum, there are parts that create and runtime, and use function selector to find and execute body of function.
I have built geth on my computer from a source code, and then modified to print the running opcode.

After that, I compiled the following smart country contents and made a js file.

```
  contract A {
      uint num;
      constructor (uint n) public {
          num = n;
      }

      function add(uint n) public {
          num += n;
      }

      function nums() public view returns (uint) {
          return num;
      }
 }
```

js file is like,

```
var aBin="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"
  var aAbi =[{"inputs": [{"internalType": "uint256","name": "n","type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "no    npayable","type": "constructor"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "n","type": "uint256"}],    "name": "add","outputs": [],"stateMutability": "nonpayable","type": "function"},{"inputs": [],"name": "num    s","outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256","name": "", "type": "uint256"}],"stateMutability": "view","type"    : "function"}]
```

And,

```
> loadScript("test1/A.js")
true
> var aAbi = aAbi
undefined
> var aBin = '0x'+aBin
undefined
> var conA = eth.contract(aAbi)
undefined
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "*mypassword*")
true
> var contractA = conA.new(2,{from:eth.accounts[0], data:aBin, gas:'7000000'})
```

when I try to execute add function,

```
> contractA.add.call(1)
```

Opcodes looks like this

```
[op: PUSH1, operation: 943840]
[op: PUSH1, operation: 943840]
[op: MSTORE, operation: 93ee00]
[op: CALLVALUE, operation: 93c020]
[op: DUP1, operation: 94c830]
[op: ISZERO, operation: 9398f0]
[op: PUSH1, operation: 943840]
[op: JUMPI, operation: 93f570]
[op: JUMPDEST, operation: 93f720]
[op: POP, operation: 93ebe0]
[op: PUSH1, operation: 943840]
[op: CALLDATASIZE, operation: 93c500]
[op: LT, operation: 938d10]
[op: PUSH1, operation: 943840]
[op: JUMPI, operation: 93f570]
[op: PUSH1, operation: 943840]
[op: CALLDATALOAD, operation: 93c2d0]
[op: PUSH1, operation: 943840]
[]
```

If you look at the output opcode, it was finished before reach to function selector (`1003e2d2`).

If performed correctly, ADD opcode should exist but is not visible in the output results.

What do I have to do to execute function?

Comment: In web3.js, `contractA.add.call(1)` would return a `Promise` object which you would then need to resolve in order for the RPC to the node to complete. Perhaps that is why.

Comment: In addition to that, you have created an `eth.contract` object named `contractA` but you haven't used it in order to actually deploy the contract that this object represents, so I don't see how it can work regardless of the issue that you've mentioned.

Comment: So that is mean, there's no way to call a function from within the console and execute it?

Comment: I believe so, but it still doesn't explain why you're not seeing the function-selector in the bytecode of the function-call.

Comment: Oh wait - that `[]` at the end of your "Opcodes" output - are you sure it's not just a truncation of the printout by geth console (so the function-selector is further down there, but just wasn't printed)?

Comment: Since I only added the output statement to the interpreter, I doubt that part. Then it is better to look at the function selector or other parts.

Comment: Then I suggest you start with what I've mentioned in the first two comments.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Did any of that solve your problem?

Comment: @atti The deployment code seems fine since you are using geth's console which uses web3 0.20. The opcode output is truncated it doesn't make much sense to end like that.

Comment: @Ismael I can't understand why opcode output is truncated.....

Comment: @atti The first part checks if ether was sent (CALLVALUE operator), the second part check the sent message's length (CALLDATASIZE), the last part is reading the message (CALLDATALOAD), but does nothing with it. A complex alternative would be to deploy a geth private archival node then use debug_traceTransaction to inspect the execution.

Answer (score 1):

It is because geth setting was wrong.
I need to set genesis block to other instead of Homestead.